# Sybase initializes but does not run

Tags: sybase

I am using Red Hat 5.5 and I am trying to run Sybase ASE 12.5.4.

Yesterday I was trying to use the command "service sybase start" and the console showed sybase repeatedly trying to initialize, but failing, the main database server.

UPDATE:

I initialized a database at /ims_systemdb/master using the following commands:

```
dataserver -d /ims_systemdb/master -z 2k -b 51204 -c $SYBASE/ims.cfg -e db_error.log
chmod a=rwx /ims_systemdb/master
ls -al /ims_systemdb/master
```

And it gives me a nice database at /ims_systemdb/master with a size of 104865792 bytes (2048x51240).

But when I run

```
service sybase start
```

The error log at /logs/sybase_error.log goes like this:

```
00:00000:00000:2013/04/26 16:11:45.18 kernel  Using config area from primary master device.
00:00000:00000:2013/04/26 16:11:45.19 kernel  Detected 1 physical CPU
00:00000:00000:2013/04/26 16:11:45.19 kernel  os_create_region: can't allocate 11534336000 bytes
00:00000:00000:2013/04/26 16:11:45.19 kernel  kbcreate: couldn't create kernel region.
00:00000:00000:2013/04/26 16:11:45.19 kernel  kistartup: could not create shared memory
```

I read "os_create_region" is normal if you don't set shmmax in sysctl high enough, so I set it to 16000000000000, but I still get this error.  And sometimes, when I'm playing around with the .cfg file, I get this error message instead:

```
00:00000:00000:2013/04/25 14:04:08.28 kernel  Using config area from primary master device.
00:00000:00000:2013/04/25 14:04:08.29 kernel  Detected 1 physical CPU
00:00000:00000:2013/04/25 14:04:08.85 server  The size of each partitioned pool must have atleast 512K. With the '16' partitions we cannot configure this value f
```

Why do these two errors appear and what can I do about them?

UPDATE:

Currently, I'm seeing the 1st error message (os cannot allocate bytes).  The contents of /etc/sysctl.conf are as follows:

```
kernel.shmmax = 4294967295
kernel.shmall = 1048576
kernel.shmmni = 4096
```

But the log statements earlier state that

```
os_create_region: can't allocate 11534336000 bytes
```

So why is the region it is trying to allocate so big, and where did that get set?

Comment: What Sybase product are you running?  Assuming it's ASE, what does the Sybase ASE Log say?  Typically it's in the installation directory under ~/ASE-??_??/install/NAME_OF_DB_SERVER.log  The question marks correspond to the version of ASE you are running (15_0,15_5,15_7 etc).

Comment: Hi Michael. I looked under ASE-12_5/install and I didn't find any log statements. I did, however, find some relevant info in /logs/sybase_error.log, which I've posted above. I also managed to initialize a database using the dataserver command, and if you are interested I can post the output of that here.

Comment: Look in the install directory, there should be a file corresponding to the name of your dataserver, with the prefix RUN_  Instead of running dataserver, try running the ASE_12-5/install/startserver -f RUN_NAME_OF_DB_SERVER.  Make sure no other instances are running (./install/showserver) before you try to start it.  Post the entries from thy sybase error log after you run that command.

Comment: From the looks of things, the Sybase ASE instance is configured to use more memory then has been allocated by the OS for it to use.  You may want to look at this RH document on shared system memory for databases  https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/chap-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Setting_Shared_Memory.html

Comment: So I've looked into my sysctl file, and I've set SHMMNI=4096 (down from 8192), SHMALL=1048576 (4G/4k), and SHHMAX=4G-1.

Comment: When I run "startserver -f RUN_SYBASE" or dataserver like I've been doing, the kernel tries to allocate 11534336000 shared bytes.  But that is 110 times the size of the database I am trying to create.  How did it grow so large?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution:

When you get a message like "os_create_region: can't allocate 11534336000 bytes", what it means is that Sybase's configuration file is asking the kernel to create a region that exceeds the shmmax variable in /etc/sysctl.conf

The main thing to do is to change ims.conf (or whatever configuration file you are using). Then, you change the max memory variable in the physical memory section.

```
[Physical Memory]
    max memory = 64000
    additional network memory = 10485760
    shared memory starting address = DEFAULT
    allocate max shared memory = 1
```

For your information, my /etc/sysctl.conf file ended with these three lines:

```
kernel.shmmax = 16000000000
kernel.shmall = 16000000000
kernel.shmmni = 8192
```

And once this is done, type "showserver" to reveal what processes are running.

For more information, consult the Sybase System Administrator's Guide, volume 2 as well as Michael Gardner's link to Red Hat memory management in the comments earlier.